# Making raster layer 1 meter high using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, 3d

I have 30 raster layers of the subsurface. Each representing the subsurface 1 meter below one another. I would like to have a 3D view of this like voxels. Each layer must have an artificial height of 1 meter.
There is no need to make calculations with the volume. Just the picture "must look nice".

How do I do this using ArcGIS Pro?

[image: raster layers to make voluminious like voxels]

Comment: Don't you just need to extrude the (constant) surfaces by one meter?

Comment: aha thanks. I didnt know the word I was looking for is called "extrusion".
Now I read  that Extrusion is only possible for points, lines and polygons.

"The three basic geometry types—points, lines, and polygons—all support extrusion. Other geometry types, such as multipatch, raster, and annotation features, do not support extrusion. As a result, the extrusion option is automatically disabled in the feature's layer properties."
So what I want is not possible. Thanks.